# Select data from a duplicated foreign key in a table

Tags: mysql

well... I have the following tables:

```
Team
fields: id_team, name
```

and

```
Team_Match
fields: id_team1, id_team2, id
```

What I need is a query that calls the `"name"` of `"id_team1"` and `"id_team2"` in the same query, these ids are foreign keys from the `"Team"` table `"id_team"` field.

Is this possible or do I need a query for each one?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: The answer is that it is possible.  You should give it a shot and post what you've tried.  I'll tell you that you will wind up with 2 join statements in your query.

Comment: Hint: you can join the same table multiple times, just use a different alias every time.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about tables aliases, you people helpep me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple joins here to get this. The first join can be between `team_match` and `team` for team1, to get team1's name. Then you can join again on team2 to get team2's name. Just be sure to alias your tables clearly:

```
SELECT t1.name AS team1Name, t2.name AS team2name
FROM team_match t
JOIN team t1 ON t1.team_id = t.team1_id
JOIN team t2 ON t2.team_id = t.team2_id;
```